# Define custom HTML elements

Tags: html

I am writing an HTML file and using a lot this:

```
<iframe src="blablabla" width=100% height=555 frameBorder=0></iframe>
```

Is it possible to somehow define `myiframe` such that I can set this width, height and frame border in the definition and then just do
`<myiframe src="blablabla"></myiframe>`
?

Comment: This feature is called web components: https://www.robinwieruch.de/web-components-tutorial - but maybe in your case CSS will actually suffice

Comment: If you just want to change the elements visually, use css classes <iframe class="myClass"> and define the css properties. If you need to add in functionalities use web components as @CherryDT suggested, or a similar framework like vuejs or react.

Comment: Can you show me an example? This is requires JavaScript/CSS/something other than pure HTML? Sorry, I have almost no experience in this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to somehow define `myiframe` such that I can set this
> width, height and frame border in the definition and then just do
> `<myiframe src="blablabla"></myiframe>` ?

Yes, it is.

And though **WebComponents** are an incredibly powerful tool (and I very much hope they will continue to increase in popularity), in this situation you just need **CSS**:

**Working Example:**

```css
.myiframe {
  width: 200px;
  height: 180px;
  border: 3px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<iframe class="myiframe" srcdoc="blablabla"></iframe>
```

---

The simplest way to start with CSS is go to the `<head>...</head>` of your **HTML Document** and add the following, somewhere in the document head:

```
<style>

  .myiframe {
    width: 200px;
    height: 180px;
    border: 3px dashed red;
  }

</style>
```

Comment: Where should I write `.myiframe ...`? I tried in some random part at the beginning of my HTML file and it does not seem to work.

Comment: Normally you will put your styles in a separate document (a stylesheet) and you will link to the stylesheet from your HTML document, using: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystylesheet.css">`. But you can _also_ add `<style>...</style>` to the `<head>` of your document and add your styles there.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, You can. These Custom Components are called Web Components.
For More info, take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements). (To make things easy, you can switch to ReactJS).

But, In your case, Adding a CSS will apply the styling to every iframe element.

`iframe{ width:100%; height:555px; }`

---

Implementation (Put style tag after head tag) -

```
<style>
    iframe{ 
      width:100%; 
      height:555px; 
    }
</style>

<body>
 <iframe src="blablabla" frameBorder=0></iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: Where do I have to write this? I wrote it in the beginning of my HTML file and it does not work.